# tightening python data structure validation using Validator

Tags: python, json, schema

I am trying to test if a json file is **identical** to a standard json file. using valideer:

```
import valideer as V
product_schema = {
     "+id": "number",
     "+name": "string",
     "+price": V.Range("number", min_value=0),
     "tags": ["string"],
     "stock": {
         "warehouse": "number",
         "retail": "number",
     }
 }
validator = V.parse(product_schema)
```

3 examples, two are doing what is needed, and the third one passes though it should fail:

```
 product1 = {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Foo",
      "price": 123,
      "tags": ["Bar", "Eek"],   
      "stock": {
          "warehouse": 300,
          "retail": 20
      } }

validator.is_valid(product1) # gives true, which makes sense (identical schema)
```

another example

```
 product2 = {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 123,  }

validator.is_valid(product2) # gives False, since the schema are different
```

my problem is with the case where we have extra features:

```
product3 = {
          "id": 1,
          "extra id": 12,
          "name": "Foo",
          "price": 123,
          "tags": ["Bar", "Eek"],
          "Hi" : "bar",   
          "stock": {
              "warehouse": 300,
              "retail": 20
          } }

validator.is_valid(product3) # gives true! though the schema are different!
```

This causes a problem when trying to make a unit test to make sure the schema didn't change. How can I can make sure that the 3rd care will give False?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add "additional_properties" flag
[Valideer github page](https://github.com/podio/valideer)

```
validator = V.parse(config_schema, additional_properties=False)
```

Now we run the three examples:

```
validator.is_valid(product1)  # gives true
validator.is_valid(product2)  # gives false
validator.is_valid(product3)  # gives false
```